# hibernate sessionFactory keep try connect to database till 5 min

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Hi my requirement is to test db connection, if db is down than try to connect for specific period of time (5 min).
i am using sessionFactory in HibernatUtil class below is the code,

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        return new Configuration().addProperties(getHibernateProperties())
                                  .addAnnotatedClass(VersionInfo.class)
                                  .buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    getSessionFactory().close();
}
```

now in the above code if db is down it will through ExceptionInInitializerError and terminate the application. but my requirement is it should keep trying to connect to database for 5 min with provided properties, if its still not reachable than exit the application.
Can any one give idea or suggestion about i proceed.